# Processes tracing each other

Tags: c, linux

I am trying to create a child process, wich asks its parent to trace him. After this the child tries to attach to its parent. Because of some protection reasons processes can trace only their children, so I have to execute my code with `sudo`. I want to create some communication between the two processes, therefore I put a do-while loop in the parent. If the child terminates the parent should terminate too. My output is only `Child is traced`, so I assume that the child does not attach to the parent.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/ptrace.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

void child();
void parent(pid_t pid);

int main() {
    pid_t pid = fork();
    if(pid == 0)
        child();
    else if(pid > 0)
        parent(pid);
    else{
        perror("fork");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}


void child(){
    if(ptrace(PTRACE_TRACEME, 0, 0, 0) < 0){
        perror("ptrace");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    printf("Child is traced\n");


    pid_t ppid = getppid();
    if(ptrace(PTRACE_SEIZE, ppid, NULL, NULL) != 0) {
        perror("ptrace");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    printf("Child is tracing\n");

    raise(SIGTRAP);

    ptrace(PTRACE_DETACH, ppid, NULL, NULL);

    printf("%s\n", "Child exiting...");
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}


void parent(pid_t pid){
    int status;
    do{
        waitpid(pid, &status, WUNTRACED | WCONTINUED);
        if(WIFSTOPPED(status)){
            printf("Child stopped: %d\n", WSTOPSIG(status));
            if(WSTOPSIG(status) == 5){
                printf("Stopsig status 5.\n");
            }
            ptrace(PTRACE_CONT, pid, 0, 0);
        }
    } while(!WIFEXITED(status) && !WIFSIGNALED(status));

    ptrace(PTRACE_DETACH, pid, NULL, NULL);

    printf("%s\n", "Parent exiting...");
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Commenting out the `raise(SIGTRAP)` I get:

```
Child is traced
Child is tracing
Child exiting...
Parent exiting...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A ptraced process will, by default, get stopped when a signal is delivered to it. When your child raises SIGTRAP, a SIGCHLD signal is sent to the parent. Since the parent is being traced, it stops, as does the child. Deadlock.

If you add code to have the parent ignore SIGCHLD, the program runs as expected:

```
Child is traced
Child is tracing
Child stopped: 5
Stopsig status 5.
Child exiting...
Parent exiting...
```